# Añadir nueva columna en posición especifica

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla de `sql server` donde guardo archivos, y lo que quiero es agregar una nueva columna específicamente entre 2, después de la columna de ArchivoAdmin que tengo.

He estado intentado con este código pero me da error en la palabra de `column` y en el tipo de dato `varchar(MAX)`

```
alter table CatListaDePrecios
add column ArchivoAdminNombre varchar(MAX)
after ArchivoAdmin
```

Entre la columna de `ArchivoAdmin` y `ArchivoProveedor`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Añade siempre los errores completos EN las preguntas. "Me da error" no es una descripción del error

Comment: Lo tendré en cuenta en futuras preguntas, gracias.

Comment: ESto es una mala idea, por mas que se pueda hacer.. el orden de las columnas se modifica facilmente en el select....

Comment: pero lo que quiero no es una consulta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No lleva la palabra column, te recomiendo quitar la palabra MAX y colocar el número máximo que permita tu ersión.

Si el after no funciona, puedes ir a la pestaña de Herramientas-> Opciones->Designers
y asegurate de que la casilla "Impedir guardar cambios que requieran volver a crear tablas" no esté seleccionada. Así podras entrar al diseño de la tabla y moverla manualmente.

```
alter table CatListaDePrecios
add ArchivoAdminNombre varchar(MAX)
after ArchivoAdmin
```

Comment: Gracias, creo que repetiste la respuesta.